# Connection issue for dual LED utility light

Tags: wiring, lighting

I have a 3700 Lumen 4000K Dual 4ft LED Utility Light mounted on upper side of a wall. It has a 5ft wire attached to it. The outlet is around 10 ft away, so I used an extension cord to complete the setup. But now I found out that this is not the right way to do it. I don't use this light often so for now I have just removed it. But I want to fix the setup.

1. Can I use a power strip instead of extension wire? Will that be ok? I can mount the power strip on the wall where the wire for the light reaches.
2. 2nd options is to re-wire from the light itself. Remove the original wire and add a complete new 10 ft wire. The issue is that in the light the wires are soldered to the circuit and I am not sure what is the wire gauge. It looks like 18 but how can I be sure? Where can I get the replacement wire with a plug attached?
3. Are there any other options to fix this situation? I am just an amateur trying to fix this. Can't run additional lines or install new outlets in wall like I read in some other posts. :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where are you located? Are you asking for a legal solution, a safe solution, or a convenient solution?

Comment: In an apartment complex edison NJ. i want safe and legal solution. convenient one was extension cord which i want to get rid off.

Comment: OK; what kind of utility light is this? Does it come with its own plug (three-prong, hopefully)? A picture might be helpful.

Comment: ya it came with a 2 prong plug. this is the light i have , got it from costco. Instead of hanging from top i have fixed it to side wall. https://www.feit.com/products/fixtures/utility/led-lampsled_utility_lights73991/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power strip vs extension cord make no difference.  They are the same thing.  Generally you are not allowed to use flexible cords as a substitute for the fixed wiring of a structure.

However, NEC 400.7 specifically allows the use of flexible cords for luminaires.  The minimum permissible wire gauge in such a lamp cord would be 16 AWG.

I don't know if this exception extends to extension cords.  I suspect it does not.

There is no problem using a longer cord.  There's no maximum cord length in the NEC.  However you must install it properly with good strain reliefs.  If you don't know where to find a longer cord, go to Target in the extension cord section and do not leave the section until inspiration strikes!

Check the writing on the cordage to determine its size and type, and make sure this is a type legal for use as cordage.  Most likely it will be.

I would not recommend soldering it to a board.  If there is a metal-enclosed place on the lamp which is suitable, I would leave several inches of the old cord, and use wire-nuts to splice the old cable to the new.  Mind polarization: the edge of the cord will have ribs or a stripe, which goes to the wider blade on the cord, aka neutral.  Polarize the new cord the same way.  This splice must happen inside a metal-enclosed part of the lamp, and it cannot interfere with the strain relief protecting the cord from damage.  Without a ground wire, it's especially important you don't cut open a wire or short it to chassis.